# Let $A,B$ be nonempty sets of a finite additive group $Z$.Show that there exists an $x\in Z$ such that $1-|A\cap (B+x)|/|Z|\leq(1-|A|/|Z|)(1-|B|/|Z|)$

Tags: additive-combinatorics, probabilistic-method

Let $A,B$ be nonempty sets of a finite additive group $Z$.Show that there exists an $x\in Z$ such that $$1-\frac{|A\cap (B+x)|}{|Z|}\leq \left(1-\frac{|A|}{|Z|}\right)\left(1-\frac{|B|}{|Z|}\right)$$
and a $y\in Z$ such that
$$1-\frac{|A\cap (B+y)|}{|Z|}\geq \left(1-\frac{|A|}{|Z|}\right)\left(1-\frac{|B|}{|Z|}\right)$$

This exercise is from Tao and Vu's Additive Combinatorics and here is what I have tried:
Randomly pick an $y\in Z$, and assume $|A|\geq |B|$, then we have $|A\cap (B+x)|\leq |A|$. Hence
$$1-\frac{|A\cap (B+y)|}{|Z|}\geq \left(1-\frac{|A|}{|Z|}\right)\geq  \left(1-\frac{|A|}{|Z|}\right)\left(1-\frac{|B|}{|Z|}\right)$$
Taking expectation w.r.t. $y$ and the result follows. The case $|B|\geq |A|$ is similar.
But I have no idea how to get the upper bound.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there are some wrongs in description. Taking $A=B=\{0\}$ and $1-\frac{|A\cap(B+x)|}{|Z|}\ge 1-\frac{1}{Z}> (1-\frac{|A|}{|Z|})(1-\frac{|B|}{|Z|})$

Comment: @GuangyiZou Thank you for your reply. The question says the inequality is true for any finite additive groups and any nonempty subsets. So we don't necessarily have strict inequality for all sets.

Comment: @Ishigami Guangyi is saying that the problem is false, since you can have an example where the LHS is strictly greater than the RHS. If you look on Terry Tao's blog, you'll see that this question had an error, look at the erratum for this book.

Comment: @mathworker21 Hi thank you for your reply. I didn't know there is a typo and I am able to solve it now, thank you so much for your help!